# Сделать форму поиска в Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: поиск, форма, ms-access

Ранее никогда не работал Access. Столкнулся с задачей сделать форму поиска по фамилии, имени, отчеству или телефону.
Идея такая. Создать ленточную форму, кинуть на эту форму поле для ввода и кнопку поиск.
Подскажите. Как можно сделать такой поиск?

Comment: Ленточную-то зачем? обычную одиночную непривязанную... которую можно воткнуть в форму вывода как подчинённую. Либо добавить поля фильтра в, скажем, заголовок формы вывода.

Comment: Можно конечно и так. Ленточную я где-то видел. Показалось удобно. А как фильтр добавить ? Я раньше вообще таким не занимался.

Comment: Да никак... свободные поля, и всё... а по нажатию кнопки накладываете соотв. условия на источник данных формы либо фильтр на саму форму.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант с вложенной формой. Вы создаете обычную не привязанную форму и сверху добавляете 4 текстовых поля: фамилия, имя, отчество, номер телефона; + кнопку поиска. Ниже встраиваете форму табличного или ленточного вида с данными из источника данных. Далее на событие `Click` кнопки вешаете обработчик:

```
dim flag as Boolean, sqlstr as String
flag = False
If IsNull(Me.Controls("телефон").Value) Then
    sqlstr = "Select * From table Where"
    If not IsNull(Me.Controls("фамилия").Value) Then 
        sqlstr = sqlstr & "[фамилия] = '" & Me.Controls("фамилия").Value & "'"
        flag = True
    End If
    If not IsNull(Me.Controls("имя").Value) Then
        If flag Then sqlstr = sqlstr & " and"
        sqlstr = sqlstr & "[имя] = '" & Me.Controls("имя").Value & "'"
        flag = True
    End If
    If not IsNull(Me.Controls("отчество").Value) Then
        If flag Then sqlstr = sqlstr & " and"
        sqlstr = sqlstr & "[отчество] = '" & Me.Controls("отчество").Value & "'"
        flag = True
    End If
Else
    sqlstr = "Select * From table Where [телефон] = '" & Me.Controls("телефон").Value & "'"
End If
With Me.Controls("форма_с_данными").Form
    .ResordSource = sqlstr
    .Requery
    .Refresh
End With
```

предполагается, что поля форм имеют русские названия, соответствующие названиям полей таблицы.

---

Если предполагается поиск по частичному тексту полей, то следует заменить в тексте запросов знак равенства на оператор `Like`. Например:

```
// Вот этот кусок кода
sqlstr = sqlstr & "[фамилия] = '" & Me.Controls("фамилия").Value & "'"

// будет выглядеть вот так
sqlstr = sqlstr & "[фамилия] Like '" & Me.Controls("фамилия").Value & "'"
```